# XSLT output two documents based on array variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml file with structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">

    <changeSet author="system" id="65D7AFA9-17F1-4406-997E-D2B42A0E9008" dbms="oracle">
        <sql>GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ${dbSchema}.CATALOG TO ${appUser}</sql>
        <rollback>REVOKE SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ${dbSchema}.CATALOG FROM ${appUser}</rollback>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="system" id="E2731435-DCEE-4B7E-BA60-20A87E75227A" dbms="oracle">
        <sql>GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ${dbSchema}.CATALOGATTRIBUTE TO ${appUser}</sql>
        <rollback>REVOKE SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ${dbSchema}.CATALOGATTRIBUTE FROM ${appUser}</rollback>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="system" id="65D7AFA9-17F1-4406-997E-D2B42A0E9008" dbms="oracle">
        <createTable ...>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I'd like to output all `changeSet`s where sql contains one of `tables` to one document and all others (which doesn't contain the table name) to other document. I was thinking about appending stuff to variable and at the end print two variables, but that doesn't work (or I don't know how to process further).

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:uuid="http://uuid.util.java"
               exclude-result-prefixes="uuid">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="tables"
                  select="('CATALOG','CATALOGATTRIBUTE','EVENTTYPES')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="changeSet[sql]">
        <xsl:variable name="changeSet" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="sql" select="sql"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$tables">
            <!--<xsl:variable name="selected" select="sql[contains(text(),concat('${dbSchema}.', ., ' '))]"/>-->
            <xsl:variable name="tableName">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($sql, $tableName)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$changeSet"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

can I somehow gather all `changeSet` which match `tables` and then all `changeSets` which doe not?

ps: I'm using Saxon-HE-9.8.0-14 for processing.

Thanks

Comment: You can select e.g. `//changeSet[$sql[every $table in $tables satisfies contains($sql, $table)]]` to select all `changeSet` elements where the `sql` elements string value contains every string in the `tables` variable. Not sure whether that helps. You haven't explained which result you want.

Comment: Martin I've tried to put your matcher to template but it complains `Variable sql has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)`. I would like to have both results if possible (maybe separate them to files?).

Comment: Sorry, somehow I prefixed the `sql` with a dollar, should have been `//changeSet[sql[every $table in $tables satisfies contains(., $table)]]`.

Comment: hm, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but that prints the entire document without applying the template maybe. Can you post example? I was trying something like this: ```<xsl:template match="changeSet[sql[every $table in $tables satisfies contains(., $table)]]"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:copy-of select="changeSet"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>```

Comment: Note that `CATALOGATTRIBUTE` contains `CATALOG` - so if you're going to use `contains()` as your test, then testing for `CATALOGATTRIBUTE` separately  is redundant.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that I've changed the contains to ```contains(., concat('${dbSchema}.',$table, ' '))``` but that still didn't worked for me.

Comment: I think it would be better to **tokenize** the `sql` contents before making the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<databaseChangeLog>
    <changeSet>
        <sql>ALPHA,BRAVO,CHARLIE</sql>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet>
        <sql>BRAVO,CHARLIE,DELTA</sql>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet>
        <sql>DELTA,ECHO,FOXTROT</sql>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet>
        <sql>FOXTROT,GOLF,HOTEL</sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="tables" select="('BRAVO', 'GOLF')"/>

<xsl:template match="/databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:variable name="group1" select="changeSet[some $t in $tables satisfies contains(sql, $t)]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <group1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$group1"/>
        </group1>
        <group2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="changeSet except $group1"/>
        </group2>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog>
   <group1>
      <changeSet>
        <sql>ALPHA,BRAVO,CHARLIE</sql>
      </changeSet>
      <changeSet>
        <sql>BRAVO,CHARLIE,DELTA</sql>
      </changeSet>
      <changeSet>
        <sql>FOXTROT,GOLF,HOTEL</sql>
      </changeSet>
   </group1>
   <group2>
      <changeSet>
        <sql>DELTA,ECHO,FOXTROT</sql>
      </changeSet>
   </group2>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiP

---

A better solution would be to use `tokenize()`:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="tables" select="('BRAVO', 'GOLF')"/>

<xsl:template match="/databaseChangeLog">
    <xsl:variable name="group1" select="changeSet[tokenize(sql, ',') = $tables]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <group1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$group1"/>
        </group1>
        <group2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="changeSet except $group1"/>
        </group2>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYiP/1